# Парсинг данных в соц сети с помощью selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium, beautiful-soup

цель-сбор открытых данных о пользователях соц сети

```
    import requests
url = 'https://www.interpals.net/' 
page = requests.get(url)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
!pip install selenium

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/***/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.interpals.net')

inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id('topLoginEmail')
inputElement.send_keys("***")


inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id('topLoginPassword')
inputElement.send_keys("***")
inputElement.submit()

import time
time.sleep(3)

driver.get('https://www.interpals.net/app/search?offset=&sort=last_login&age1=20&age2=40&sex%5B%5D=male&sex%5B%5D=female&photo=1&online=1&countries%5B%5D=---&countries%5B%5D=---&city=&cityName=&continents%5B%5D=AF&continents%5B%5D=AS&continents%5B%5D=EU&continents%5B%5D=NA&continents%5B%5D=OC&continents%5B%5D=SA&languages%5B%5D=---&languages%5B%5D=---&lfor%5B%5D=lfor_snail&lfor%5B%5D=lfor_langex&lfor%5B%5D=lfor_friend&lfor%5B%5D=lfor_meet&lfor%5B%5D=lfor_relation&keywords=&sort=last_login&username=&csrf_token=YjFiNzQ4Nzc%3D')
```

Вот на этой стадии начинается проблема:
теперь мне необходимо собрать информацию, которая есть в профиле найденных пользователей (язык, образование, интересы и тд)
Пробовала такой код:

```
profile = driver.find_element_by_name("View profile").click()  #открываем профиль
profile.submit()

soup0 = BeautifulSoup(page0.text, 'lxml')

research = [name, location, speak, learning, lookfor, education] #в каждом профиле ищем информацию о языке, интересах, образовании   
for i in profile:
    name = soup0.find_all('</h1>') #что нужно писать в скобки, чтобы отбирался  нужный нам текст ?
    location = soup0.find_all('a', {'href' : 'country'})[0].text
    speak = soup0.find_all('div', {'<h3>' : 'Speaks'})[0].text
    learning = soup0.find_all('div', {'<h3>' : 'Learning'})[0].text
    lookfor = soup0.find_all('div', {'<h3>' : 'Looking for'})[0].text
    education = soup0.find_all('div', {'<h3>' : 'Education'})[0].text
    return #как повторить это для всех найденных пользователей- сделать скролинг?

group_infos = get_counts(research)  
group_infos.shape

group_infos.to_excel('research.xlsx')   
group_infos.to_csv('research.csv')
```

ошибка

```
    NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"View profile"}
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.80)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
```

логика должна быть такая, ошибка в поиске метатегов, исходный код страницы можно посмотреть по ссылке https://www.interpals.net/

это пример кода профиля, откуда мы берем информацию

```
<div class="profileBox">
<h1 style="display: inline; font-size: 16px; color: #8442A2;">raduyus
&nbsp;&nbsp;</h1> Margarita, 29 y.o.
<img src="https://cdn-eu.ipstatic.net/images/female-14.png" width="14" height="14" style="margin-left: 3px; margin-top: 4px;vertical-align: top;">
<div class="profDataTop">
<div class="profDataTopField profLocation">
<div class="profDataTopData" style="width: 355px; ">
<a href="/country/RU" class="nobreak" style="float: left; width: 25px; margin-top: 2px;">
<img src="https://cdn-eu.ipstatic.net/images/flags/iso/24/RU.png" width="24" height="24">
</a>
<div style="float: left; width:255px; margin: 5px;">
<a href="/app/search?todo=search&city=524901">Moscow</a>,
<a href="/country/RU">Russia</a>
<span style="color: #ccc;">[Current City]</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="profOnlineStatus">
<div class="online-now"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Online now</div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
<div class="profDataTopField" style="background: #fff">
<h3>Speaks</h3>
<div class="profDataTopData">
<a href="/app/search?todo=langex&languages%5B%5D=RU" title="Find other penpals who speak Russian" class="profLang">
<div class="prLangName"><img src="https://cdn-eu.ipstatic.net/images/flags/langs-40x40/ru.png" width="14" height="14" alt="Russian" class="langFlag" />Russian
</div>
<img src="https://cdn-eu.ipstatic.net/images/lang_bars/4.png" class="proflLevel" width="13" height="10">
</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="profDataTopField" style="background: #fff">
<h3>Learning</h3>
<div class="profDataTopData">
<a href="/app/search?todo=langex&languages%5B%5D=KO" title="Find other penpals who speak Korean" class="profLang">
<div class="prLangName"><img src="https://cdn-eu.ipstatic.net/images/flags/langs-40x40/ko.png" width="14" height="14" alt="Korean" class="langFlag">Korean
</div>
<img src="https://cdn-eu.ipstatic.net/images/lang_bars/1.png" class="proflLevel" width="13" height="10">
</a>
<a href="/app/search?todo=langex&languages%5B%5D=ZH" title="Find other penpals who speak Chinese" class="profLang">
<div class="prLangName"><img src="https://cdn-eu.ipstatic.net/images/flags/langs-40x40/zh.png" width="14" height="14" alt="Chinese" class="langFlag">Chinese
</div>
<img src="https://cdn-eu.ipstatic.net/images/lang_bars/1.png" class="proflLevel" width="13" height="10">
</a>
<a href="/app/search?todo=langex&languages%5B%5D=EN" title="Find other penpals who speak English" class="profLang">
<div class="prLangName"><img src="https://cdn-eu.ipstatic.net/images/flags/langs-40x40/en.png" width="14" height="14" alt="English" class="langFlag">English
</div>
<img src="https://cdn-eu.ipstatic.net/images/lang_bars/1.png" class="proflLevel" width="13" height="10">
</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="profDataTopField" style="background: #fff;">
<h3>Looking for</h3>
<div class="profDataTopData">
<div class="lfor">Friends</div>
<div class="lfor">Language practice</div>
</div>
</div>
<h3>Education</h3>
<div class="profDataTopData">
Graduate degree
</div>
<div class="profDataTopData">
</div>
</div>
<div class="profDataTopField" style="background: #fff;">
```

Comment: Ваша ошибка говорит, что Селениум не смог найти элемент с таким именем. Уточните, что на странице действительно есть такой элемент с таким именем, или используйте любой другой метод поиска, css-селектор или xpath адрес например

Answer (score 0):

```js
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedrv\\chromedriver.exe'
opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# opts.add_argument('headless')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts, executable_path=chromedriver)
browser.implicitly_wait(20)
browser.get('https://www.interpals.net/')

le = browser.find_element_by_id("topLoginEmail")
le.send_keys("user_name")
lp = browser.find_element_by_id('topLoginPassword')
lp.send_keys("password")
lp.submit()

# печать своего профиля
alist = browser.find_element_by_class_name('memberLinks').find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
for a in alist:
    if(a.text == 'My Profile'):
        a.click()
        break
pb = browser.find_element_by_class_name('profileBox')
print(pb.text)
db = browser.find_element_by_class_name('profDataBox')
print(db.text)
print('\n')

# печать чужих профилей на странице поиска
browser.get('https://www.interpals.net/app/search')
rlist = browser.find_element_by_id('sRes').find_elements_by_class_name('sResCont')
for r in rlist:
    a = r.find_element_by_class_name('sResLinks').find_element_by_tag_name('a')
    print(a.text)
    a.click()
    pb = browser.find_element_by_class_name('profileBox')
    print(pb.text)
    db = browser.find_element_by_class_name('profDataBox')
    print(db.text)
```

Для поиска и чтения данных профиля пользователя interpals.net достаточно функций   Selenium. Другие библиотеки не требуются. Кроме того, вы использовали ошибочный способ навигации при переходе на страницу профиля.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]